# How to protect your code from exceptions thrown by external Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When including an external JS file on a page, if it throws an exception it can sometimes halt all other JS from running.

What causes some code to break, and some to continue working?

What is the best way to protect your code from breaking?

Comment: You could apply a global exception handler to window.onerror

Comment: do you have any example of an unhandled exception which halt ALL other JS from running? An unhandled exception will make the current context fail, but if you call any other function JS will run again.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how a **context** is defined.